# Power plug in Ireland: is it the same as in the rest of Europe?

Tags: europe, power, ireland

What kind of power plug is used in Ireland?

Is it the typical plug used in most of Europe? Or is it the British one?

(Could you attach or link to a photo so I can make sure?)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's the same as the British one [(Type G)](http://electricaloutlet.org/type-g). [(Type D)](http://electricaloutlet.org/type-d) was once common and may be occasionally found. The voltage in Ireland is the same as the rest of Europe (220 volts).

To be more specific, From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets):

> The British Standards 1363 plug[17] is used in the United Kingdom and other countries. Compatible plugs standards are IS 401 and IS 411 (Ireland), MS 589 (Malaysia) and SS 145 (Singapore), and SASO 2203 (Saudi Arabia).

This is how it looks:

[image: UK power outlet]

**Bath and shower rooms**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets):

> In the United Kingdom and Ireland, there is a two-pin socket for use with electric shavers in bath or shower rooms.[18] It derives from the unearthed version of 5–6 A British plug and it has 0.2 in (5.08 mm) diameter pins 5⁄8 in (15.88 mm) apart. The sockets for this plug are often designed to accept unearthed CEE 7/16, US or Australian plugs as well. Sockets are often able to supply either 230 V or 115 V. In wet zones, they must contain an isolation transformer compliant with BS 3535.

[image: UK Shavers]

For more details, check [the electrical outlet website](http://electricaloutlet.org/) for a list of the electrical plug types for the whole world.

Comment: It may be worth adding that the voltage is the same as the rest of europe, it's just the plug that differs

Comment: Actually in UK, Ireland and mainland EU it's no longer 220V, it's been 230V for quite a few years now.

Comment: @vartec: To be precise, the EU-wide standard since 2008 has been 230 V ±10%, where the permitted 10% range of variation is cleverly chosen to cover both the 220 V and the 240 V standards previously used in different countries, with plenty of room on either side for actual voltage fluctuations. So the *nominal* voltage is 230 V nowadays, but the *actual* voltage you're getting may well be closer to 220 V (or 240 V or even 250 V), depending on where in Europe you happen to be.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, it's the same as the UK.

Ireland & the UK are quite culturally close (and were the same country until 1922), so anything bought in the UK would have to work in Ireland. There are numerous 'high street' UK chains operating in Ireland selling the same merchandise.

Comment: There used to be issues whereby UK televisions wouldn't work completely or at all in Ireland, as some channels in Ireland were VHF which the UK boxes couldn't receive. Post-digital though, this is not a problem any more.