# What legal documents are Italian citizens supposed to carry when traveling to Ireland?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, ireland, power, italian-citizens

This summer I would like to go on vacation in Ireland for two weeks with my girlfriend.  I'm 21, she is 19 years old. We're Italian. I have a driver's license and carta d'identità.

**Question:** As an Italian citizen, what legal documents are we supposed to carry when we travel to Ireland? Also what electrical adapter (for mobile and laptop) should I carry with me?

Comment: We don't prepare itineraries here. But the question about documents may be on topic if it hasn't been answered before.

Comment: recommendations, prices, where to go all are considered off topic

Comment: @MarcoBagiacchi: it is a question (the original one) better fit on the Thorn Tree Forum. StackExchange network's policies are usually against opinions, discussions and so on, as it does not want to be a replacement for forums. On the other hand, Thorn Tree Forum's target is exactly that, asking for opinion and discussing them.

Comment: Short answer: For travel within the EU, you need some legal ID, either your Italian citizen's ID card, or alternatively a passport. Driver's licenses are not a suitable form of ID, and only useful for driving cars. Regarding which plugs are used in Ireland: Wikipedia has the information.

Comment: Leave the gun. Take the cannoli.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> As an Italian citizen, what legal documents we are supposed to carry when we will be traveling to Ireland?

Passport or national ID card (*carta d'identità*), provided it does not say *non valida per l'espatrio* on the back. If the *carta* does say this then it is not valid as a travel document outside of Italy.

> Also what electrical adapter (for mobile and laptop) I should carry with me?

[Ireland uses British BS1363 sockets,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7536/power-plug-in-ireland-is-it-the-same-as-in-the-rest-of-europe?rq=1) so you'll need an adapter.

Comment: If you use the "carta d'identita" it should have "valida per l'espatrio" written on it.

Comment: I always used my ID without any indication of "valida per l'espatrio" written on it. The only thing that could be written is "*non* valida per l'espatrio"", for the opposite reason. Source (one of many): http://bit.ly/2eDI61b

Comment: For the lazy, and for those who can't read Italian, here's a cleaned-up machine translation of the relevant bit from @Banex's link: **Validity for foreign travel** On an Identity Card that is valid for travel abroad no particular words appear; on the contrary, on ID cards that are not valid for travel abroad the words appear: "not valid for foreign travel."
We point out that there are states that do not allow access to the country to travelers in possession of paper ID cards renewed with stamp,

Comment: "so you'll need an adapter" - not necessarily: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8rKlRP-Kn0

Answer (score 9):

You need either a *carta d'identità* or passport to enter Ireland - a driving licence is not a travel document and as such will not do.

Granted, in actuality anyone who can prove beyond reasonable doubt that they are an EEA national (a driving licence alone is not sufficient for this) should be let in by immigration authorities, but good luck getting on a plane with that argument - airlines may face a hefty penalty for transporting a passenger inadmissible to the destination country.

Answer (score 1):

Irish sockets are the same as UK ones, the 13Amp (Type-G). 50Hz, at 230V
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types#BS_1363_three-pin_.28rectangular.29_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: Oops, didn't notice his link.

Comment: This is an answer to a question about legal documents??

Comment: @user987234: The question does include the sentence *"Also what electrical adapter (for mobile and laptop) should I carry with me?"* This is a valid answer to that part. That's what happens when questions include too many different sub-questions.